# Logging of different species of INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a four kind of inserting data in table in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnList) VALUES (ValuesList)

INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnList) SELECT Columns FROM OtherTable

INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnList) EXEC SomeProc

SELECT Columns INTO TableName FROM OtherTable
```

Every INSERT statement is logged in transaction log, and my question is what kind of INSERT has minimal logging?

What is the order in using, based on performance?

Comment: Why would you think that these have different logging requirements?  The logging of `insert` is a function of the number of rows being inserted, not the method for finding the rows (although there may be overheads for a stored procedure call or select statement separate from the insert logging).

Comment: Your last query is also different to the previous ones, since it needs to create a table first

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because I was reading that second option can benefit from minimal logging, since for other that isn't noticed.

Comment: @veljasije Maybe this links can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx and http://sqlserverplanet.com/data-warehouse/sql-server-2008-minimally-logged-inserts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) has a good summary of minimally logged operations:

> To support high-volume data loading scenarios, SQL Server implements
>   minimally logged operations. Unlike fully logged operations, which use
>   the transaction log to keep track of every row change, minimally
>   logged operations keep track of extent allocations and metadata
>   changes only. Because much less information is tracked in the
>   transaction log, a minimally logged operation is often faster than a
>   fully logged operation if logging is the bottleneck. Furthermore,
>   because fewer writes go the transaction log, a much smaller log file
>   with a lighter I/O requirement becomes viable.

Out of the different types of insert statements you provided, two can be classified as bulk load operations, which have the *opportunity* to be minimally logged if other prerequisites have been met:

> - `INSERT ... SELECT` – The method for performing bulk load in process with SQL Server from local queries or any OLE DB source. This
>     method is only ailable as a minimally logged operation in SQL Server
>     2008.
> - `SELECT INTO` – The method for creating a new table containing the results of a query; utilizes bulk load optimizations.

However, note that there are prerequisites and conditions that need to be met in order for one of these bulk load operations to be minimally logged...

- Running the database under the  [Bulk-Logged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190692%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or [Simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191164%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) recovery models
- [Enabling Trace Flag 610 if you're running Sql Server 2008 or newer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/10/24/new-update-on-minimal-logging-for-sql-server-2008.aspx)
- Whether or not the table has a clustered index
- Whether or not the table is empty
- Even the *execution plan chosen by the optimizer*

If you meet these conditions, then you may see better performance by performing a bulk logged `insert` as described in the article...

But again, the prerequisites for this happening are pretty complex, so I would recommend reading the article before creating / changing commands with the expectation that they will be minimally logged.

EDIT:

One clarification... Note that it is the recovery model of the destination database that is relevant.  For example, if you're inserting into a temporary table from tables in a database that has a full recovery model... since the temporary table resides in `tempdb`, which has a simple recovery model, the insert into the temporary table is a good candidate to be written as a bulk-logged operation in order to be minimally logged.